# Cannot validate my csrf-token using csurf (Node.js)

Tags: node.js, csrf-protection

I am unable to use csurf in this basic test application, no matter what I do I always get "ForbiddenError: invalid csrf token" after sending a form.

What am I doing wrong? I am trying to follow the example given [in the documentation for csurf](https://github.com/expressjs/csurf#example) (although I am using TLS as well - could that affect the results?).

```
'use strict'

var https = require('https');
var express = require('express');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
var csrf = require('csurf')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var fs = require('fs');
var oauth = require('./oauth.js');
var argv = require('minimist')(process.argv.slice(2), {
    alias: {p: 'port'},
    default: {port: 80},
});

// setup route middlewares
var csrfProtection = csrf({ cookie: true })
var parseForm = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })

var app = express();

app.use(cookieParser());

// Init SSL
var sslPath = '/etc/letsencrypt/live/censored/';
var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync(sslPath + 'privkey.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(sslPath + 'fullchain.pem')
};

app.get('/some-form', csrfProtection, function(req, res){
        res.send('<form action="/process" method="POST">' +
                    '<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="' + req.csrfToken() + '">' +
                    'Favorite color: <input type="text" name="favoriteColor">' +
                    '<button type="submit">Submit</button>' +
                    '</form>');
});

app.post('/process', csrfProtection, function(req, res){
        res.send('<p>Your favorite color is "' + req.body.favoriteColor + '".');
});


app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.send('Hello World!');
});
app.listen(argv.port, function() {
    console.log('listening on port ' + argv.port);
});

https.createServer(options, app).listen(443);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to use the `parseForm`, once i did that everything worked fine!